# Definition of class of continuously differentiable functions on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

This is a technical simple question.  The space $C^1([a,b])$ is defined as

$$C^1([a,b])=\{f:[a,b]\to R: \exists\; f' \textrm{ and is continuous on } [a,b]  \}.$$

I think there is some explaining to do here, and is the fact that $f'$ cannot be defined at $a$ or $b$ because those points do not belong to the interior of the domain. The question is:

In the above definition, $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ are understood in the sense of right and left derivatives respectively? If not, in which sense?

Comment: Yes, they are intended in that sense.

Comment: A usual approach is to define $C^1\big([a,b]\big)$ as the set of all functions $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that are the restriction to $[a,b]$ of some $C^1$ function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$, where $U \supsetneq [a,b]$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

A derivative can in fact be defined on the edge of a domain. For example, let $f(x): [0, 1] \to [0,1]$ be defined by $x \mapsto x$. Then $f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$. This limit exists and is equal to 1. Proof: let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbritrary. Choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Let $x$ satisfy $0 < |x - 0| < \delta$ and $x \in [0, 1]$, which is $x \in ]0, \delta[$. Then $|f(x)/x - 1| = |x/x - 1| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Comment: When you are taking $x\to 0$, you are implicitly assuming that $x$ can take values in some neighborhood of $0$: $\lvert x - 0 \rvert < \delta$ is the same as the $-\delta < x < \delta$, so $x$ can be negative. However, a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ isn't defined for $x < 0$ so you need to be careful. What you are really doing here is taking a right side derivative; it is a bit misleading to say that we can define the derivative of $f$ at $0$ when $f$ is undefined for $x < 0$.

Comment: $x$ cannot be negative because $x$ needs to be in the domain of the function.

Comment: I know, but if you are going to define the derivative at $x= 0$, you need to be allowed to take $x < 0$ or $x > 0$ (that is, the definition of the limit allows for a **two-sided** approach toward $x= 0$). Since $x=0$ is a boundary point here, we can only take the limit in one direction and thus we aren't really taking a derivative; we're only taking a **one-sided** derivative.  This is why it is a bit simplistic to say "a derivative can in fact be defined on the edge of the domain" and then plow ahead with the original definition. It can be defined; but in a slightly different sense.

Comment: Which definition of the derivative do you use? No definition I know, nor could find on the internet, say you need to be able to take $x < 0$ or $x > 0$.

Comment: It's implicit in $$\lim_{x \to 0}$$ that $x$ should be allowed to take values in a neighborhood of $0$. Otherwise, you use $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \,\,\,\,\, \text{ or } \,\,\,\,\, \lim_{x\to 0^-}$$ to specify that $x$ is approaching from one side. The reason there is typically no need to specify is because we teach differentiation at interior points of closed intervals or on the real line.

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 0}$$ has no meaning, you need to know of what function and domain you take the limit. It is fine if you want to define limits like you do, but that is not the way everyone else defines limits, so that will cause confusion. If I were you, I'd just stick to the conventional definitions.

Comment: I realize you need an argument; I just suppressed that bit. I define the limit like everyone else: the limit of $g(x)$ as $x \to 0$ is the number $L$ (if it exists) satisfying: for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$, such that $0 < \lvert x \rvert < \delta$ implies that $\lvert g(x) - L \rvert < \epsilon$. What I am saying is, $0 < \lvert x \rvert < \delta$ allows for $-\delta < x < 0$ or $0 < x < \delta$; i.e. $x$ can approach zero from either side. By way of example, consider the function $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$ for $x \in A \subset \mathbb R$. If we use your reasoning above with...

Comment: $A = [0,1]$, we find that $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(0) = 1$. But if we use the definition of the derivative with $A = [-1,1]$, then $f'(0)$ doesn't exist. This is why it is somewhat reductive to say that "A derivative can in fact be defined on the edge of a domain." It is more correct to say that a **one-sided** derivative can be defined on the edge of the domain. It is because of this technicality that we typically only define the derivative in the interior of the domain (indeed, the technicality becomes worse when we raise the dimension which in complex analysis, ...

Comment: we only define holomophicity in the interior of a domain; see, for example, Terry Tao's notes: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/246a-notes-1-complex-differentiation/#more-9352). All of this is usually brushed under the rug in a calculus course because the students are learning calculus very formally but these are important details in an analysis course.

Comment: @User8128 in definition of limit when function is defined on the metric space $X$  we choose inputs inside of $X$ ... here $X = [0, 1 ]$.

Comment: I voted up , since it is logically true. The reason that in many situation it is preferable to be assumed derivative only on interior point is that derivative on boundaries usually don't give us expected information of function, for example if minimum of f be on boundary f' doesn't have to be zero on that point